# How do I add a data property to an offline leaflet map from react props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet as an offline map for a website. Basically, I am mapping the countries by importing them from a big(13.000 line) javascript file a la this codepen: http://codepen.io/dagmara223/pen/jydMqy

I am however coloring each country a specific color depending on a data input passed as a react props.

I have the data structure for `dataratio` typed out, but it can be accessed with the commented out code as well.

Here's my `worldmap.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import countries from './countries.js';

var Worldmap = React.createClass({


    getInitialState: function(){
        let geolocation =  [];

        // let dataratio = this.props.data;

        let dataratio =  {
                "JPN": "25",
                "RUS": "91",
                "SWE": "67",
                "NOR": "82",
                "USA": "13"
            };

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            let lat = position.coords.latitude;
            let lon = position.coords.longitude;


            if(lat != null && lon != null) // If we can get latitude and longitude, reset geolocation and push values.
                geolocation.length = 0;
                geolocation.push(lat, lon);
            if(!lat || !lon) // If we can't get latitude or longitude, set a default value.
                geolocation = [0,0];

            let map = L.map('leafletmap').setView(geolocation, 3); // Map will center on geolocation, on zoom level 3 per default.

            let info = L.control();

            info.onAdd = function (map) {
                this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
                this.update();
                return this._div;
            };

            info.update = function (props) {
                this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Data ratio</h4>' +  (props ?
                    '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.data + ' ratio'
                        : 'Hover over a country');
            };

            info.addTo(map);


            function getColor(d) {
                return d > 90 ? '#4a1486' :
                    d > 75  ? '#6a51a3' :
                        d > 50  ? '#807dba' :
                            d > 25  ? '#9e9ac8' :
                                d > 15   ? '#bcbddc' :
                                    d > 5   ? '#dadaeb' :
                                        d > 1   ? '#f2f0f7' :
                                            '#D3D3D3'; // Default color of data doesn't exist or is 0.
            }

            function style(feature) {
                return {
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: 'white',
                    fillOpacity: 1,
                    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.data) // That's where we get the ratio if it exists in the country
                };
            }

            function highlightFeature(e) {
                let layer = e.target;

                layer.setStyle({
                    weight: 5,
                    color: '#666',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7
                });

                if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
                    layer.bringToFront();
                }

                info.update(layer.feature.properties);
            }

            let geojson;

            function resetHighlight(e) {
                geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
                info.update();
            }

            function zoomToFeature(e) {
                map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
            }

            function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                layer.on({
                    mouseover: highlightFeature,
                    mouseout: resetHighlight,
                    click: zoomToFeature
                });
            }


            geojson = L.geoJson(countries, { // We're taking 'var countries' from countries.js
                style: style,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);

            let legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

            legend.onAdd = function (map) {

                let div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                    grades = [1, 5, 15, 25, 50, 75, 90],
                    labels = [],
                    from, to;

                for (let i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                    from = grades[i];
                    to = grades[i + 1];

                    labels.push(
                        '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                        from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
                }

                div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
                return div;
            };

            legend.addTo(map);
        });


        return (
            <div>
                geolocation
            </div>
        )
    },
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div id="leafletmap" style={{width: "100%", height: "95%", border: "2px solid black" }} />
        )
    }
});

export default Worldmap
```

Basically right now, for example, if I want to color say Russia, I simply add the property "data" manually with a key value and add it in there, such as:

```
{
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "RUS",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Russia",
                "data": "91"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [143.648007, 50.7476],
                        // Coordinates go on ..
```

And it correctly colors Russia with the > 90 color :-)

My question therefore relates to integrating the `dataratio` to write into a completely separate .js file; The key("RUS" for example) is compliant with the structure of countries.js; but how do I actually add a key value store into this huge countries.js file?

Should I manipulate the `var countries` in that given countries.js file? Or should I integrate this in my worldmap.js if so, I am not sure how to do it by matching the keys from another js file.

The way leaflet works in this case is that it fetches into the countries.js and by itself matches the key to the value. I'm torn as to whether or not I should make the countries.js into a React class and manipulate it that way, but it's a massive file and performance could be of concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the following way:

```
let dataratio = {
            "RUS": "91",
            "NOR": "22",
            "SWE": "91",
            "UKR": "25",
            "GER": "21"
        },

// let dataratio = this.props.data;


let dataratioToArr = Object.keys(dataratio).map(data => [ data, dataratio[data]]); // Conv. map to multidimensional array

let featuresArr = countries.features; // array of all countries in array features from countries.js

for(let i = 0; i < featuresArr.length; i++) // i = 178(no. of countries)
    for(let j = 0; j < dataratioToArr.length; j++) // j = amount of countries we have with dataratio > 1 from backend
        if(dataratioToArr[j][0] == featuresArr[i].id) // If ISO-3 compliant ID of country(f.e. "JPN" or "USA") matches, push a "data" property to countries.js
            featuresArr[i].properties.data = dataratioToArr[j][1];
```

This basically alters the countries.js in-memory so long as the `dataratio` doesn't keep the values but is not pushed if it doesn't exist.